# How to specify target platform ios version number in Codemagic

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, codemagic

I am trying to build ios version of my app on Codemagic without a Mac. The build fails with the following messages.

```
 [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "flutter_facebook_login":
  In Podfile:
    flutter_facebook_login (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_login/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `flutter_facebook_login (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_facebook_login/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

It seems that ios version requirement of flutter_facebook_login package is higher than ios 8. I think it will be solved if I can specify a higher ios version.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I solved the issue by manually creating Podfile as in the following.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!

def parse_KV_file(file,seperator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  pods_ary = []
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
      next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
      plugin = line.split(pattern=seperator)
      if plugin.length == 2
        podname = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
        pods_ary.push({:name => podname,:path=>podpath});
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
  }
  return pods_ary
end

target 'Runner' do
  # Flutter Pods
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file("./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig")
  if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
    puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter build or flutter run is executed once first."
  end
  generated_xcode_build_settings.map{ |p|
    if p[:name]=='FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
      pod 'Flutter', :path => p[:path]
    end
  }

  # Plugin Pods
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file("../.flutter-plugins")
  plugin_pods.map{ |p|
    pod p[:name], :path => File.expand_path("ios",p[:path])
  }
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can uncomment the target in podfile.
or you can add

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

at the top of you pod file. you can specify the version you need inside the quote

Comment: I already tried it. Now I have another error: fatal error: module 'FBSDKCoreKit' not found

Comment: try pod install, after deleting the Podfile.lock and pods folder in the directory

Comment: I dont have mac. Is it possible on windows?

Comment: I think you need a mac to build your ios application. Because you nedd to insttal pods file and also need xcode to take the buld

Comment: Codemagic and some others claim that it is possible without a mac. It is frustrating.